# Provide a friendly message when attempting to save an answer to question that's been closed

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions

As a follow-up to my question [What should I do with my frustration at having a question closed after writing a thoughtful answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133002/what-should-i-do-with-my-frustration-at-having-a-question-closed-after-writing-a), I wonder if it would be reasonable to provide a kindly-worded pop-up to a user attempting to save an answer to a closed question.

As a new user trying to participate by providing good answers, but who hasn't yet learned the nuance of which apparently well-written (if "off-topic") questions will be insta-closed, it might be useful to provide a more respectful user-experience acknowledging that their contribution is valued, and explaining why this has happened.

As it stands now, I believe the answerer just finds the "Save" button has become disabled, and upon page refresh he/she learns the question has been closed. The ten minutes spent composing the answer are wasted. I believe the site's UI should acknowledge and thank the poster for his/her contribution, encourage them to continue providing answers, and maybe offer a link to the relevant FAQ.

Comment: extremely closely related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93081/notification-of-question-closure-whilst-answering closely related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111395/when-writing-an-answer-can-we-be-notified-if-people-are-voting-to-close http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81042/see-close-votes-as-they-come-in same train of thought: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129474/allow-users-to-post-in-progress-answers-even-to-questions-that-get-closed http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26136/could-there-be-a-countdown-before-questions-are-closed

Comment: Related, yes, but I'm specifically speaking of the user-experience when attempting to save an answer to a question that's actually been (as opposed to might be) closed.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for what the text should be?